# The makefile enviroment variable "BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH", where to find the document?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

The BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH  shell variable can be used to direct the Makefile compiled codes, and when running `build clean`, the make command can clean the *.o files according to  BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH, which is useful to construct a big project.
I've known how to use it, but failed to find the corresponding documentation.
I've refered to the "GNU make manual", used the man, info command, nothing found.

Comment: There is no special meaning to `BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH` in GNU Make, either in the tool itself or by convention.  If that variable does something special, it's because your specific makefile environment is coded to do something special with it.  If you want to know what it does and how it works you'll have to examine your makefiles and see how it's used and what it does.

Comment: I don't see the point in posting the ChatGPT answer here.  What do you want us to say about it?

Comment: Well, the ChatGPT answer is probably nothing more than a guess. But to certain degree, it helps me to understand the `BUILD_OUTPUT_PATH`. It can't usually be right.
Thank you @MadScientist and I will try to figure out if there is something special in the project's Makefiles.

Comment: I'm not questioning why you would consult ChatGPT.  If it's helpful that's good.  I'm just questioning why the output of ChatGPT was posted in the question you asked as that doesn't seem relevant to someone reading your question.

Comment: And the meaningless ChatGPT answer deleted.

Comment: Please see my first comment above.  If that doesn't answer your question then you'll need to edit your question to provide more details.